# Apache CXF with JAX-WS - WSDL differences with Axis2 Generated WSDL

Tags: web-services, wsdl, cxf, jax-ws, apache-axis

We have legacy application, uses java-first approach for SOAP webservices. We were using axis2 till now but decided to migrate to apache CXF with JAX-WS. We re-wrote the code and did necessary spring xml changes to generate WSDLs. But we are facing one major issue in generated WSDL which is little different than Axis2 one, which in-turn causing contract breakage with clients. For example, we have below API exposed in interface:

```
public OTPB2BResponse validateOTP(@WebParam(name = "otpB2BRequest") OTPB2BRequest otpB2BRequest);
```

In generated WSDL, it looks like this:

**Axis2:**

[image]

**CXF with JAX-WS:**

[image]

For input message, axis2 showing as ***operationName*Request** with Action as ***operationName*** where as in CXF, it just shows ***operationName*** without any Action.

But i want to generate the WSDL same as Axis 2. I'm clueless what went wrong and i tried various options on `@WebParam` annotation but none of them are working. I even tried with `@RequestWrapper` annotation but no luck.

I have 10s of webservices which are generated like this causing contract breakage with clients.  Is there any way to generate WSDL same as like Axis2 ?